# Bootstrap Popover Requires Second Click Before Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

This makes you click twice before you can get the image and popover to appear, but after you have do that then it works as hoped where when you click on the next one the previous one disappears and the new one appears. Also, I think this can be consolidated. Any help would be appreciated. Here's a codepen example: [Boostrap Popover Timeline](https://codepen.io/benjino/pen/qVVRxz)

```
$(".timeline-list-btn").on('click', function() {
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover()
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).popover('hide')


  $("#1-btn").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': 'url(../img/help/help1.svg) no-repeat center center',
      'background-color': '#4359AB',
      'background-size': "65px, 65px",
      'transform': 'scale(0.75, 0.75)',
      'box-shadow': 'none',
    });
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).css({
      'background': 'white',
      'transform': 'scale(0.25, 0.25)',
    });
  });

  $("#2-btn").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': 'url(../img/help/help2.svg) no-repeat center center',
      'background-color': '#4359AB',
      'background-size': "65px, 65px",
      'transform': 'scale(0.75, 0.75)',
      'box-shadow': 'none'
    });
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).css({
      'background': 'white',
      'transform': 'scale(0.25, 0.25)'
    });
  });

  $("#3-btn").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': 'url(../img/help/help3.svg) no-repeat center center',
      'background-color': '#4359AB',
      'background-size': "65px, 65px",
      'transform': 'scale(0.75, 0.75)',
      'box-shadow': 'none'
    });
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).css({
      'background': 'white',
      'transform': 'scale(0.25, 0.25)'
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the functions. The single answer to my issue was .mousedown() on the wrapping function, simple as that. Check it out below:

```
$(".timeline-list-btn").mousedown(function() {
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover()
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).popover('hide')
// Wrap the above functions into a trigger function here


  $("#1-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': 'url(../img/help/help1.svg) no-repeat center',
      'background-color': '#4359AB',
      'background-size': "65px, 65px",
      'transform': 'scale(0.75, 0.75)',
      'box-shadow': 'none',
    });
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).css({
      'background': 'white',
      'transform': 'scale(0.25, 0.25)',
    });
  });

  $("#2-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': 'url(../img/help/help2.svg) no-repeat center',
      'background-color': '#4359AB',
      'background-size': "65px, 65px",
      'transform': 'scale(0.75, 0.75)',
      'box-shadow': 'none'
    });
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).css({
      'background': 'white',
      'transform': 'scale(0.25, 0.25)'
    });
  });

  $("#3-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': 'url(../img/help/help3.svg) no-repeat center',
      'background-color': '#4359AB',
      'background-size': "65px, 65px",
      'transform': 'scale(0.75, 0.75)',
      'box-shadow': 'none'
    });
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(this).css({
      'background': 'white',
      'transform': 'scale(0.25, 0.25)'
    });
  });
});
```